# error while running ionic ios build --prod --release

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, plugins, native

After installing Themeable browser plugin I am getting this error when I run :

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

I was able to build ios --prod --release without any error. Thanks :D

```
    Mac-Pro-de-chaker-2:cleantoufoulakids chakerkalai$ ionic cordova build ios --prod --realise
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform ios --target cordova
[18:22:05]  build prod started ... 
[18:22:07]  clean started ... 
[18:22:07]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[18:22:07]  copy started ... 
[18:22:07]  ngc started ... 
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
    at /Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23023:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at extractProgramSymbols (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23022:79)
    at AotCompiler.compileAll (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22720:47)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:30:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:61:30)
    at Object.doCodegen (/Users/chakerkalai/Desktop/cleantoufoulakids/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/codegen.js:6:51)
[18:22:47]  copy finished in 40.10 s
```

Comment: Also having this issue since upgrading to `"ionic-angular": "3.9.2"` and `"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0"`.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about libraries mismatching versions.

make sure you have `"typescript": "2.4.0"`and not newer.

And regarding all packages that start with `"@ionic-native/..."` their version should be `4.3.0` WITHOUT the `^` at the beginning.

and please don't upgrade to rxjs 5.5, use `"rxjs": "5.4.3"` since they changed the operators export/import.

note: if you still run into the problem of **found version 4, expected 3** remove the hat `^` from the version of the library that caused the problem.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that there was a bump to one of the `ionic-native` dependencies today (I could build less than 24 hrs ago).

I was able to work around this by removing the `^` in my package.json for all `ionic-native` dependencies:

**From:**

```
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-fetch": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/mixpanel": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/speech-recognition": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.2.1",
```

**To:**

```
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-fetch": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/mixpanel": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/speech-recognition": "4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.2.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is due to a ngc version mismatch, setting `@angular/*` to `5.0.1` should fix the issue:

```
"@angular/common": "5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
"@angular/core": "5.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
"@angular/http": "5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue for me was with `"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0"`. When I downgraded to `"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.3"` I was able to do `ionic cordova build ios --prod --release` with `"ionic-angular": "3.9.2"` again.

```
"@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
"@angular/common": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.4.6",

"@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/device": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/diagnostic": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/file": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/http": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/media": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/media-capture": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/native-storage": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/social-sharing": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.3",
"@ionic-native/themeable-browser": "4.3.3"
```

Unfortunately I couldn't upgrade to `"@angular/core": "5.0.1"` yet because `"ionic-angular": "3.9.2"` still is dependant on `"@angular/core": "4.4.6"`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was visiting https://update.ionic.zone/ and getting the updated package.json file. It will update all the dependencies to the required version.